# Teams App with Bot (WebChat) is not installable

Tags: installation, microsoft-teams, web-chat

We should install a Microsoft Teams App for our customer.
It is a chat bot with webchat, the web chat is working in browser  but installation as Microsoft Teams  App failed.

we used this manifest-file for installation anonamized with a few text parts.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.9/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.9",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "******-****-****-****-***********",
  "packageName": "tdo.chatbot1",
  "developer": {
    "name": "XXX YY",
    "websiteUrl": "https://xxxx.yyy",
    "privacyUrl": "https://xxxx.yyy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://xxx.yyy",
    "mpnId": "111111"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "chatbot1",
    "full": "chatbot1"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "A Teams App with Bot",
    "full": "TestBotTeams"
  },
  "accentColor": "#40497E",
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "conversations",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    },
    {
      "entityId": "about",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "bots": [
    {

      "botId": "*******-****-****-****-************",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ],
      "supportsFiles": false,
      "isNotificationOnly": false
    }
  ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
  "validDomains": []
}
```

The App Registration for the botid is build with default setting (only a secret was created and it was switched beteween single tenant and multi-tenant for testing).

This installation dialog shows the info of the App shown before adding it to MS Teams.
[image: Teams App info]

After clicking "Add" this error will occur.

[image: Teams App installation error]

We deployed the same bot in our tenant and installed the teams app without problems in our Microsoft Teams.

On the customer side a customer employee with enough right try to install this App but failed, then we got the permission to do do it with a test user in their teams, but we failed too. Same message.

The error message has no details, so I am complete without ideas how to fix it.

I think it is permission problem.

But if so how can we get more information and determine which permissions are missing.

**Update**: It is not at the project end phase where we must deliver a well-formed app. It is only  to show that the basic chatbot (LUIS & qna) will work in teams, no other functionallity is required at the moment, **so the minmal manifest is needed not the well-formed**. If there are parts which avoid installation so it is importand but parts for are not.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Why do you have entries in the `"staticTabs"` section if you don't have any actual tabs?

Comment: @ingo_ww -  Looks like its the issue with your app configuration or the manifest is not well-formed. Please re-verify those.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow : we only try to get the minimal config for app working, so tabs or no tabs are complete irrelevant, it is generelly not working.  same  app ,same bot works on our side but not on customer side.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft : what do you mean with well-formed? this manifest with different id's we use multiply times  and slightly changed text we used multiple times in other bots. it it script generated and in this case before posting manual checked. **What do you mean with well-formed?** this app should at this state not **fullfill** all requirements for the app-catalogue. It should only show that the webchat is working in teams. I have not the experience now to make it well-formed  and the target is to get it running at this point  - well-formed or NOT, so we could start implement requirements.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft :the manifest is valid and validation check on 
 https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/appvalidation.html shows only this failure on a icon .
Outline icon is not transparent.It's Alpha,R,G,B: 255,0,160,245 Learn to fix it
The could not really a problem for third-party app upload by direct  by user.

Comment: I might pass the validation tests, but I would remove those staticTabs sections and test again...

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow : i have tried it without the staticTabs section, but same error without no details what goes wrong. 
And it makes not really sense that it failed on this option section, because this worked for other customers and in our tenant too.

Comment: @ingo_ww - Please make sure bot channel registration is done and respective channels are added in the bot channel registration.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/shmNs.png

Comment: teams channel is registered. 
Could be a the old web app bot ressource be a problem, (but it works in our tenant but not in customer tenant) ?
Or could be configuartion entry in the bot app service  make trouble in special tenant configuration?

Comment: Old web app resource should not be a problem. Could you please re verify all your configuration values?

Comment: It seems a problem with  web app bot and/or configuration. I try to compare config entries because I have no knowledge of bot configration and installation. 
This seems to solve the teams installation, detail will follow, but it can take weeks till i have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old depreacreated Web App Bot resource, only buildabel with old arm script will avoid installing as teams app.
Using the new azure bot and it will work.